# How does Azure Function Continuous Deployment handle environment-specific transforms?

Tags: git, azure, azure-functions, continuous-deployment

I have a set of functions, some of which require environment-specific connections to Event Hubs, i.e., Function App A connects to Event Hub A, Function App B connects to Event Hub B. Given that the CD model uses branch-per-environment, how can I maintain the separate copies of function.json that drive that integration?

The dumb answer is, obviously, maintain a separate copy of function.json on each branch. This is dumb because that means "be really careful not to accidentally merge over top of your environment-specific copy and be really sorry when you forget". Ideally, there'd be something like maintaining environment specific copies, like function.DEV.json and function.QA.json. But this does not appear to be the case.

My function.json looks like this:

```
{
      "bindings": [
        {
          "type": "eventHubTrigger",
          "name": "myEventHubMessage",
          "direction": "in",
          "path": "iot-e1-ehub-dev-deviceevents-01",
          "connection": "iot-e1-ehub-dev-deviceevents-01_iothubroutes_iot-e1-iot-dev-01_EVENTHUB"
        }
      ],
      "disabled": false
}
```

So, those path and connection elements need to be different for each environment. If there's a way to manage that binding outside of function.json, I don't know about it.

Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The better solution is to keep parameters of event hubs in App Settings, and put the name of those settings in `function.json` without ever transforming it.

So, you should define your `function.json` as

```json
{
  "bindings": [
     {
       "type": "eventHubTrigger",
       "name": "myEventHubMessage",
       "direction": "in",
       "path": "%eventHubPath%",
       "connection": "eventHubConnection"
     }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

and then define `eventHubPath` and `eventHubConnection` in portal App Settings / Connection Strings (and `local.settings.json` if you are using local environment).

Comment: How does the integration code access that? That is outside the function body. Also, now it's not in version control.

Comment: You can have local settings too. Put it to git and use in integration tests.

Comment: I understand that I can have app settings - but these settings are not in the code - they are in a special Azure function file called function.json that defines the configuration context for the function.

Comment: And even I could push these to config and drive config from source control- haven't I just recreated the problem? How do I maintain different versions of the config between environments?

Comment: See my answer. Your `function.json` stays the same, your settings differ (either via portal or local.settings.json).

Comment: We're talking past each other - I'll edit my question.

Comment: Okeydoke...so the settings that are different are in the ARM template.

Answer (score 1):

Change to use app settings which, from a `function.json` perspective would look like this:

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "eventHubTrigger",
      "name": "myEventHubMessage",
      "direction": "in",
      "path": "%MyIotHubPath%",
      "connection": "MyIotHubConnection"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

In this case, `connection` already resolves a named connection string so there's no need to use variable syntax there. For `path` though, you need to use the explicit variable syntax (i.e. the `%`s).

Then you simply change the configuration values of the `MyIotHubPath` (an app setting) and `MyIotHubConnection` (a connection string setting) on a per environment basis.